# Send column number value to asp MaxLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a column in database where integer values are stored (4, 6, 8, and NULL).
These integer values are supposed to be max allowed length of TextBox, this is the [table](https://jsfiddle.net/rzhvk9fw/7/).

This is code from c# where I passed Characteristic names and integers(max number of places for textboxes from database dynamically) for now.

```
protected void ddlBC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ddlKar.Items.Clear(); 
    LogicTableAdapters.getLvLOneIntegerTableAdapter getKar = new LogicTableAdapters.getLvLOneIntegerTableAdapter();

    DataTable dtKar = getKar.getLvLOneInteger(ddlBC.SelectedValue);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]{ new DataColumn("CharacteristicName", typeof(string)) new DataColumn("MaxNoPlaces", typeof(string))});

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtKar.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr["CharacteristicName"].ToString(), dr["MaxNoPlaces"].ToString());
    }

    gvKarakteristike.DataSource = dt;
    gvKarakteristike.DataBind();
}
```

This is the ASPX markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvKarakteristike" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LevelID" OnRowDataBound="gvKarakteristike_RowDataBound">
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Characteristics">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="Characteristics" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="30px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("CharacteristicName") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOpis" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Width="142px" Height="35px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" runat="server">
                     <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                 </asp:DropDownList>

                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxOpis" runat="server"  Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text="" MaxLength='<%# Bind("MaxNoPlaces") %>'></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to this dynamically directly from database because database will grow over time so will the number of textboxes.

The problem is with this part of the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxOpis" runat="server"  Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text="" MaxLength='<%# Bind("MaxNoPlaces") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

There's an error when I run the app there:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_kn224wf0.dll but was not handled in user code

I think the problem is when the NULL value is send from the database to the asp, then it can convert it to MaxLength.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about `MaxLength='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Bind("MaxNoPlaces")) %>'`? `InvalidCastException` may occur because `MaxLength` property expects `int` value type, while `Bind` returns `string` or `object` instead.

Comment: Yes you where right. I converted string to int in c# part and then just send it tu asp and it work perfectly TNX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextBox.MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property expects value type of `int`, as in this declaration:

```
public virtual int MaxLength { get; set; }
```

Because `MaxNoPlaces` column declared with `string` data type in `DataTable` bound with `GridView.DataBind()` method, you will encounter `InvalidCastException` when binding it directly to the corresponding property. You should use `typeof(int)` and do integer conversion such like `Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.Parse()` before binding:

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]{ new DataColumn("CharacteristicName", typeof(string)), 
                    new DataColumn("MaxNoPlaces", typeof(int))});

foreach (DataRow dr in dtKar.Rows)
{
    // perform integer conversion
    dt.Rows.Add(dr["CharacteristicName"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dr["MaxNoPlaces"]));
}
```

If you done the conversion before binding to textbox control, then binding conversion like `<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Bind("MaxNoPlaces")) %>' ... />` becomes unnecessary.